# Inserting a text file into 2d array

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I want to read a text file and insert it into 2d double array. I have this code, but the first problem is that it doest not read the last column and the second problem is that it returns just the first line of my text file. For example, if the text file is

```
1.1,2.1,3.1
2.1,1.1,4.1
1.3,3.2,5.1
```

It returns:

```
{1.1 2.1}
```

How should I fix it?

```
BufferedReader match_dataset = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
Scanner src = new Scanner(match_dataset);
ArrayList<Double> lines = new ArrayList<Double>();
src.useDelimiter(",");

while (src.hasNextDouble()) {
    lines.add(src.nextDouble());
}
Double[] temp_match = new Double[lines.size()];
lines.toArray(temp_match);
```

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: i am not familar with the syntax you are using exactly but it would seem that you would need to trim the line of any extra spaces and line breaks before you attempted to get the data.  The last element is probably followed by a line break in which the src.hasNexDouble() is failing because its technically not a double but a string value of some kind.  Other than that I got nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax for a double array. Should be two brackets [][] after double